# Space between elements I can’t find

Tags: html, css

I accidentally started in quirks mode (did not declare a doctype) and when I found out that I had started in quirks mode I corrected it by declaring a doctype.

There is however one error that I cant get rid of, there is a space between .car-box-img and car-box that I cant find in inspector.

Do you know what could be the problem here? I know I could fix it by having a negative margin on .car-box but that wouldn’t help me – since I wouldn’t know what I did wrong.

I have put it on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYNQpz
But it is also here below, since stackoverflow requires it.

```
/*

CSS-RESET

*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*

HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers

*/

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*

CSS

*/

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "proxima-nova-alt", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #edede9;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#hero {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/1500x1500);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}


/*

TYPOGRAPHY

*/

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
}

h2 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: 700;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffd717;
}


/*

HEADER

*/

header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

header .header-center {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

.header-left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}

header .logo img {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 18px;
  display: block;
}

.logo-litur {
  fill: yellow;
}

header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
}

header .header-right ul li {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  float: right;
}

header .header-left ul li {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

header a {
  color: white;
}

header a:hover {
  border-bottom: 6px solid white;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/*

SEARCH

*/

.search {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  height: 78px;
  width: 435px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #bbc7cc;
 /* background-color: white;*/
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background-image:url('http://placehold.it/40x40');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position: 15px;
  font-family: "proxima-nova-alt";
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #d5e0e4;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #d5e0e4;
}

::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #d5e0e4;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
   color: #d5e0e4;
}


/*

STAFF PICKS

*/

.staff-picks {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.car-box {
  width: 430px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.car-box-img {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 235px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.car-box h3 {
  font-family: "freight-display-pro";
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.car-box p {
  border-top: 1px solid #bbc7cc;
  padding: 9px 0;
}
.car-box-footer {
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  background-color: #dee4e7;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  color: #9ba9b4;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.car-box-footer:hover {
  background-color: #ffd717;
}


<body>

  <div id="hero">
    <header>
      <div class="header-left">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Parts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end header-left -->
      <div class="header-center">
        <a class="logo" href="#"><img alt="Chariot" src="images/logo.svg"></a>
      </div> <!-- end header-center -->
      <div class="header-right">
        <ul>
          <li>User (sign out)</li>
          <li>Cart icon</li>
        </ul>
      </div> <!-- end header-right -->
    </header>
    <div class="search">
      <input type="search" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Find your dream car…">
    </div> <!-- end search -->
  </div> <!-- end hero -->

  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="staff-picks">
      <h2>Staff picks</h2>
        <article class="left">
          <img class="car-box-img" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/470x235">
          <div class="car-box">
            <h3>Chevrolet Corvette</h3>
              <p><span class="bold">Model</span> 1957</p>
              <p><span class="bold">Lorem ipsum</span> Consecetur adipiscing</p>
              <p><span class="bold">Dolor sit</span> Isicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. henderit in voluptate velit.</p>
          </div> <!-- end car-box -->
          <div class="car-box-footer">
            <p>More<i class="right">píla</i></p>
          </div> <!-- end car-box-footer -->
        </article>
        <article class="right">
          <img class="car-box-img" alt="" src="http://placehold.it/470x235">
          <div class="car-box">
            <h3>Chevrolet Corvette</h3>
              <p><span class="bold">Model</span> 1957</p>
              <p><span class="bold">Lorem ipsum</span> Consecetur adipiscing</p>
              <p><span class="bold">Dolor sit</span> Isicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. henderit in voluptate velit.</p>
          </div> <!-- end car-box -->
          <div class="car-box-footer">
            <p>More<i class="right">píla</i></p>
          </div> <!-- end car-box-footer -->
        </article>
    </section> <!-- end staff-picks -->
  </div> <!-- end wrapper -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Joseph - Stackoverflow tries to solve common question.. Could you try to turn your question in a more general one which might help others with similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

The gap is caused by your image resting on the baseline. Images are just like text and text rests upon a baseline inside its line box to allow for descenders in the type. To remove the gap, rest the image on the bottom of its linebox instead by doing

```
vertical-align:bottom;
```

[Visual formatting: line box](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#line-box)